# Custom quantity in cart for specific product

Tags: woocommerce

I have creat a function for a specific product. The customer can choose a color of object. If the customer select "RED"  the quantity input in the single product page change for a select dropdwon 10,20,30,40,50 ...

for the same product If the customer select "Green" the select change for 5,10,15,20,25 ...

In my test i have add the Red option in my cart and the Green.

Now i go in cart page, i have 2 products in cart ... Good !

But my quantity i don't know change the quantity input field for a custom select based on color.
I want displaying slect 10,20,30,40,50... for the red and 5,10,15,20,25... for the green.

I want use my custom $cart_item_data['color'] for change quantity because the product id it's same just the $cart_item_data change.

I have tried this

```
function custom_quantity_input_default( $args, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

   foreach($items as $item => $values) {

        $color = $values['color'];
          if ($color == 'red'){
            $qte = '5';
          }

    }

    $args['step'] = $qte; 

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'custom_quantity_input_default', 10, 2 );
```

But not work because args return the last numberin two product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the follows code snippets in your active theme's functions.php -

```
// for single page quantity changes
function change_quantity_product_for_variation(){
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        ( function( $ ) {
            $( document.body ).on( 'show_variation', function(event, variation) {
                var $qty = $('.single_variation_wrap').find( '.quantity' ),
                selected_color = variation.attributes.attribute_pa_color;

                // Hide or show qty input
                if ( variation.is_sold_individually === 'yes' ) {
                    $qty.find( 'input.qty' ).val( '1' ).attr( 'min', '1' ).attr( 'max', '' );
                    $qty.hide();
                } else {
                    if( selected_color == 'red' ){
                        $qty.find( 'input.qty' ).attr( 'min', '10' ).attr( 'step', '10' );
                        $qty.show();
                    }else if( selected_color == 'green' ){
                        $qty.find( 'input.qty' ).attr( 'min', '5' ).attr( 'step', '5' );
                        $qty.show();
                    }
                }
            } );
        } )( jQuery );
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'change_quantity_product_for_variation' );

// for cart quantity changes
function change_cart_item_quantity_input_field( $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ) {
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] == 0 ) return $product_quantity;
    if( !$cart_item['variation'] ) return $product_quantity;
    if ( ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        if( $cart_item['variation']['attribute_pa_color'] == 'red' ){
            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                array(
                    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                    'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                    'max_value'    => $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                    'min_value'    => '10',
                    'step'         => '10',
                    'product_name' => $product->get_name(),
                ),
                $product,
                false
            );
        }elseif( $cart_item['variation']['attribute_pa_color'] == 'green' ){
            $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                array(
                    'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                    'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                    'max_value'    => $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(),
                    'min_value'    => '5',
                    'step'         => '5',
                    'product_name' => $product->get_name(),
                ),
                $product,
                false
            );
        }
    }
    return $product_quantity;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', 'change_cart_item_quantity_input_field', 99, 3 );
```

Comment: hi itzmekhokan My product it's not a variable product. i have add in my code an custom input before_add_to_cart_button

Comment: I found a solution for my problem with your code !!! thx with the filter woocommerce_cart_item_quantity and $cart_item['data'] i retrieved my 'color' in product and i change the qty